# when $watch is called out?

Tags: angularjs, controller

Here in the code below, $watch stills takes old **newVal** not the updated one.
 I am not able to understand when $watch is called out? What if I do not want to call $watch for specific function! How this is done?

I am new to angularJs! Please help!

```
$scope.$watch('vmHome.widgets', function(newVal) {
                if (!!newVal && angular.isArray(newVal) && (newVal.length > 0)) {
                    vmHome.widgetGridConfig.data.rows = [];
                    normalizeWidgetData(newVal);
                } else {
                    vmHome.widgetGridConfig.data.rows = [];
                }
            }, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation of `$watch` from [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch). Coming to your question as to when `$watch` is called:

1. The **digest cycle** triggers `$watch`
2. You can manually trigger it using `$scope.$apply()` or `$scope.$digest()`

The digest cycle is run when a scope value changes, event triggered due to user interaction such as `ng-click`, etc.

Try this code, hope it solves your issue:

```
 $scope.$watch('widgets', function(newVal) {
  if(!!newVal && angular.isArray(newVal) && (newVal.length > 0)) {
    vmHome.widgetGridConfig.data.rows = [];
    normalizeWidgetData(newVal);
  } else {
    vmHome.widgetGridConfig.data.rows = [];
  }
 }, true);
```